# Creating geopackage layers as output with QGIS batch processing autofill option

Tags: qgis, geoprocessing, batch

Is it possible to use the *Calculate by Expression* tool to output geopackage layers. For example, with the batch option for the polygon to line function.  With the following expressions I can create individual shapefiles or individual geopackage files but not layers in a geopackage file;

This creates a separate geopackage file for each layer;`@project_folder ||'/' || @INPUT  || '_line'`

[image]
This creates a separate shapefile for each layer;
`@project_folder ||'/' || @INPUT  || '_line.shp'`

However, I can't find a way to output layers to the one Geopackage file. The Polygon to Line function seems to default to individual geopackage files if no extension is given.  The following creates output - not individual layers but separate geopackage files;
`@project_folder ||'/test.gpkg layername=' || @INPUT ||'_line`
The file names end up like this;
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To save the output of a geoprocessing algorithm into a new layer/table of an existing geopackage, you can use the following syntax:

```
ogr:dbname='C:/Path/To/Geopackage.gpkg' table="New_Table" (geom)
```

If you want to use this in *Calculate By Expression* for the outputs of a batch processing, the expression could look like the following:

```
'ogr:dbname=\'' || @project_folder || '/Lines.gpkg\' table="' || @INPUT || '_line.shp" (geom)'
```

This will return the output parameters...

[image: Example for batch processing into separate geopackge layers]

... and will create a new geopackage layer for every input:

[image: Batch processing log for separate new geopackage layers]