# QGIS append layer in one geopackage output of modeler

Tags: qgis, qgis-modeler, geopackage, batch, append

I would like to **append new layer** (created with model builder) **to a new/existing geopackage** in a **batch processing**. Tried with 3.36RC and 3.34.4 LTR.

- Every line is a csv converted to point
- Every line should have a different layer name (name of the file)
- Every line should be saved in one geopackage

[image: Processing chain in Model Buidler]
*The value in the output ('final') is empty*

[image: Output window]
**Leaving it like that will overwrite the whole file and leave only the data of the second file.**

Here is output name that I tried :

```
- D:/final.gpkg (using the dot menu on the right)
- D:/final.gpkg table="@INPUT" (dot menu + manually added table)
- ogr:dbname='D:/final.gpkg' table="@INPUT" (from the expression)
- 'ogr:dbname='||  'final.gpkg'  || ' table='|| rand(0,1000)
- 'ogr:dbname='||  'final.gpkg'  || ' table='|| 'Survey_' ||  rand(0,100)|| '.shp'
```

Trying in the drive QGIS is installed in does not change the result.

Sometime I got the following message :

```
.gpkg table="@INPUT" files are not supported as output for this algorithm.
*Changing the order of algorithms does not help.*
```

Or this :

```
    Erreur OGR : sqlite3_open(final.gpkg) failed: unable to open database file)
```

It does not have to be in the processing chain but at least in the output window of the bulk processing.

Can you help me *(or break it down if the answer already exists)* ?

links to research resources

- [QGIS model designer save back into the same geopackage](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/464882/qgis-model-designer-save-back-into-the-same-geopackage)
- [Creating geopackage layers as output with QGIS batch processing autofill option](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/373758/creating-geopackage-layers-as-output-with-qgis-batch-processing-autofill-option)
- [Fixing "Error: creation of data source failed (OGR error:Failed to create directory .shp for shapefile datastore.)"](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/93300/fixing-error-creation-of-data-source-failed-ogr-errorfailed-to-create-direct)

---

### **Partial success !**

I can export all layer in one geopackage with this :

```
ogr:dbname='D:\final.gpkg' table="data_"
=> add number after underscore   here ⬆️
```

---

### **Success on auto-naming (kinda)**

Here is what I have now (in the field calculator):

```
'ogr:dbname='
||  'D:/Data.gpkg' 
|| ' table='
|| 'data_' 
||  rand(0,100000)
```

This works at bringing each files as a layer in one geopackage. I use `rand` to create a number for the name.
I could not figure out a way to have a unique identifier. Maybe filename as a variable ? I have not find how to do that tho.

*Because it is multiple files at once, even if I use `id` the modeler will restart at the beginnning of each files.*